# Python Counter to list of elements

Tags: python, counter, python-collections

Now to flatten Counter element i'm using the code

```
import operator
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce

p = Counter({'a': 2, 'p': 1})
n_p = [[e] * p[e] for e in p]
f_p = reduce(operator.add, n_p)

# result: ['a', 'a', 'p']
```

So i'm wonder, if it could be done more directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [`Counter.elements`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter.elements)

```
p = Counter({'a': 2, 'p': 1})
p.elements()  # iter(['a', 'a', 'p'])
list(p.elements())  # ['a', 'a', 'p']
''.join(p.elements())  # 'aap'
```

Note that (per the docs)

> Elements are returned in arbitrary order

So you may want to sort the result to get a stable order.

Comment: Nice way to do !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
[i for a, b in p.items() for i in [a]*b]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'p']
```

Comment: @user3483203 Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

With just for loop:

```
from collections import Counter

p = Counter({'a': 2, 'p': 1})
plist = []
for tup in p.items():
    for n in range(tup[1]):         
        plist.append(tup[0])
print(plist)
```

output:

```
['a', 'a', 'p']
>>>
```